# Find matches in two csv files

Tags: python, csv

I have two csv files: the first one has one column called ID and 5 rows, and the second one has 12 columns (col 5 is called ID) with 100 rows. I am trying to find match IDs and write the entire row to a new csv file.

Thank you for your help!

here is my code:

```
import csv

input_file1 = "/Desktop/New1/file1.csv"
input_file2 = "/Desktop/New1/file2.csv"
output_file = "/Desktop/New1/results.csv"


with open(input_file1) as t1, open(input_file2) as t2:
    fileone = csv.reader(t1)
    filetwo = csv.reader(t2)

    with open(output_file, 'w') as output_res:
        for line in filetwo:
            if line in fileone:
                output_res.write(line)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can read the `ID`s in `file1` into a set for more efficient lookup. You should also use `csv.writer` to output the rows as CSV:

```
with open(input_file1) as t1, open(input_file2) as t2:
    ids = set(id for id, in csv.reader(t1))
    filetwo = csv.reader(t2)

    with open(output_file, 'w') as output_res:
        writer = csv.writer(output_res)
        for row in filetwo:
            if row[4] in ids:
                writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Maybe also explain why reading fileone again and again in a loop doesn't work without seeking back or closing and reopening the file; and how doing that would be mind-blowingly inefficient.